# FB.api post to multiple ids at same time

Tags: facebook, api

I'm having a little trouble here. I'm not good at `javascript` and all.

The problem is that I'm trying to post to some `Facebook` users using `FB.api`. However, it only works if it's only one friend at a time.

Here's my code:

```
   FB.api({ method: 'friends.get' }, function(result) { 
   var user_ids="" ;
   var totalFriends = result.length;
   var randNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalFriends);
   var numFriends = result ? Math.min(1,totalFriends) : 1;
   if (numFriends > 0) {
   for (var i=0; i<numFriends; i++) { 
        user_ids+= (',' + result[randNo]);
        randNo ++;
        if(randNo >= totalFriends){
            randNo = 0;
        } 
      }
    }

   FB.api(user_ids + '/feed', 'post', { message: txt2send },function(response) {
   if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
   } else {
  alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
 });
  });
```

The output of `user_ids` is looking like this: ,10083461349,100082391,19293822

Hope you can help me solve this. And please don't refer me any links to help, trust me, I've tried everything.

Answer (score 1):

> Hope you can help me solve this. And please don't refer me any links to help, trust me, I've tried everything.

Yeah, sure. But instead of sticking to what the docs say, you’re trying to invent your own “syntax” – you really think that’s helpful …?

Accessing the Graph API generally works by making HTTP requests to `/someid/someendpoint/`.

But what *you* are trying, is to (eventually) make a request to

> /,10083461349,100082391,19293822/feed

– which is just complete and utter nonsense. You just **can’t** access the Graph API listing multiple ids at once.

If you want to post to several user’s feeds, you have to make *one* API call for *each one* of these users.

Comment: Exactly; though the presence of Math.random() in there leads me to believe his app will only work for a few hours before being killed for spam reasons